# Mask column based on condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas

| class | subclass | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 02-10-22 | .5 |
| 1 | A | 02-21-22 | .6 |
| 1 | A | 02-28-22 | .8 |
| 1 | B | 02-09-22 | .3 |
| 1 | B | 02-14-22 | .4 |
| 1 | B | 02-28-22 | .5 |
| 2 | C | 02-15-22 | .9 |
| 2 | C | 02-28-22 | .8 |

I have a dataframe like above. Several (class, subclass) pairs have values ordered by dates. The bottom date for each (class, subclass) is guaranteed to be the maximum date, for example 02-28-22.

I would like to transform to the dataset below. For the date right before the maximum date, if it is not exactly 7 days before the maximum date - we change the corresponding value to NaN.  Otherwise we leave it alone, as well the other dates. FE, the row with date 02-21-22 is left alone; while the row with 02-14-22 is now NaN.

Dates are stored as strings: '02-15-22'.

| class | subclass | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 02-10-22 | .5 |
| 1 | A | 02-21-22 | .6 |
| 1 | A | 02-28-22 | .8 |
| 1 | B | 02-09-22 | .3 |
| 1 | B | 02-14-22 | NaN |
| 1 | B | 02-28-22 | .5 |
| 2 | C | 02-15-22 | NaN |
| 2 | C | 02-28-22 | .8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the max date and the second max date using `groupby`. Then use `where` to mask the relevant values:

```
maxdate = df.groupby(["class", "subclass"])["date"].transform('max')
nextmaxdate = df.groupby(["class","subclass"])["date"].transform(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).min())

df["value"] = df["value"].where(df["date"].ne(nextmaxdate) | maxdate.sub(nextmaxdate).dt.days.eq(7))

>>> df
   class subclass       date  value
0      1        A 2022-02-10    0.5
1      1        A 2022-02-21    0.6
2      1        A 2022-02-28    0.8
3      1        B 2022-02-09    0.3
4      1        B 2022-02-14    NaN
5      1        B 2022-02-28    0.5
6      2        C 2022-02-15    NaN
7      2        C 2022-02-28    0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate reverse `cumcount` to identify the row preceding the last row, then `group` and `shift` the `date` column and subtract a offset of `7 days`, then `mask` the values in `value` column preceding to last row where the required condition is not met

```
c = df[::-1].groupby(['class', 'subclass']).cumcount()
d = df.groupby(['class', 'subclass'])['date'].shift(-1) - pd.DateOffset(days=7)
df['value'] = df['value'].mask(df['date'].ne(d) & c.eq(1))
```

---

```
   class subclass       date  value
0      1        A 2022-02-10    0.5
1      1        A 2022-02-21    0.6
2      1        A 2022-02-28    0.8
3      1        B 2022-02-09    0.3
4      1        B 2022-02-14    NaN
5      1        B 2022-02-28    0.5
6      2        C 2022-02-15    NaN
7      2        C 2022-02-28    0.8
```